# mtouch argument -aot "nimt-trampolines=512" is causing build failure on VS for Mac 17.3.6 (20)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

After upgrading Visual Studio to version `17.3.6 (build 20)`, the Xamarin.iOS project is failing to build with the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(4,4): Error MSB4028: The "ParseBundlerArguments" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "Aot" parameter. Parameter "includeEscaped" cannot have zero length. (MSB4028)
```

The problem lies in the project file itself:

```
 <MtouchExtraArgs>-i18n=west -aot "nimt-trampolines=512" --registrar:static</MtouchExtraArgs>
```

It's complaning about -aot parameter and it's value. If I replace it with as following (space replaced with equal sign) then all is compiling fine:

```
<MtouchExtraArgs>-i18n=west -aot="nimt-trampolines=512" --registrar:static</MtouchExtraArgs>
```

Does anyone can help to confirm that this is a new correct way for specifying the `-aot` parameter?

My VS details:

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.3.6 (build 20)
Installation UUID: 2895cffa-b375-4042-bae5-5ad18ed7c073

Runtime
.NET 6.0.5 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.3.0-3.22312.2+52adfb8b2dc71ed4278debcf13960f2116868608

NuGet
Version: 6.2.1.2

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.401
    3.1.423
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.9
    5.0.17
    3.1.29

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.19
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.3.0.208
Hash: 0de472ea0
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:23:48 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336)
Build 14A400

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-3/030cd63
Android SDK: /Users/danielklokov/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        12.1 (API level 32)
        12.0 (API level 31)
        11.0 (API level 30)
        13.0 (API level 33)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 33.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 32.0.0

Build Information: 
Mono: dffa5ab
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-3@7716ae53
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.5@df4deab
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@14076a6

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.12
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.3.0.23
Hash: 965bf40
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:23:52 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1169
Hash: fafb1d5
Branch: fafb1d5
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:23:52 UTC

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 16.0.0.72 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 6756a1146
Branch: release/6.0.4xx-xcode14
Build date: 2022-09-21 08:51:06-0400

Build Information
Release ID: 1703060020
Git revision: f7a6334599543f127e737d6de1f362bbe36cebca
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:21:08+00
Build branch: release-17.3
Build lane: release-17.3

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.6.0
Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0
    Mon Aug 22 20:17:10 PDT 2022
    root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: What if you add an extra `-` ahead `aot`  like  `<MtouchExtraArgs>-i18n=west --aot="nimt-trampolines=512" --registrar:static</MtouchExtraArgs>`, may I confirm if it is compiling fine?

Comment: it is compiling with and without extra `-` as soon as I add `=` between parameter and the value, which suggest this is wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `-aot` parameter like below:

```
--aot=ARGUMENT

Add ARGUMENT as an argument to the static compiler.
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Would this compile and run `--aot=nimt-trampolines=512` with two equals signs?

Comment: Btw double `-` is used with conjunction `:` e.g. `--aot:ARGUMENT`

Comment: If  `-aot="nimt-trampolines=512"` compiles well, you should use it instead of `-aot "nimt-trampolines=512"` .

Comment: it does compile, but I'm not convinced it's been accounted during compilation